# Adding additional functions within a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm starting to write more jQuery plugins within their own namespace so I can re-use code and to keep my code DRY.

I'm new to the whole plugin authoring, but read a few sources including the official jQuery one.

Here is an example I found that I'm playing around with:

```
(function($) {
    // jQuery plugin definition
    $.fn.reverseText = function(params) {
        $.fn.reverseText.test();
        // merge default and user parameters
        params = $.extend({
            minlength: 0,
            maxlength: 99999
        }, params);
        // traverse all nodes
        this.each(function() {
            console.log($(this).parent().data('url'));
            // express a single node as a jQuery object
            var $t = $(this);
            // find text
            var origText = $t.text(),
                newText = '';
            // text length within defined limits?
            if (origText.length >= params.minlength && origText.length <= params.maxlength) {
                // reverse text
                for (var i = origText.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) newText += origText.substr(i, 1);
                $t.text(newText);
            }
        });
        // allow jQuery chaining
        return this.each;

    };
    // Is this correct?
    $.fn.reverseText.test = function() {
    alert('test');
    };
})(jQuery);


$(function() {
    $(".js-test-whatever li:even").reverseText();
});
```

Generally I'd create a namespace like this:

```
 var a = {

    };

    a.reverseText = {
        init: function () {
         reverseText(); 
        });
    },

    reverse: function() {
     $(function() {
        return foo;
      });
    }

    a.reverseText.init();
```

So what's the proper way to add multiple functions within a jQuery plugin namespace?

Look at the comment in the first example of where I included an additional function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an acceptable way to do it. Another way to do it could be like this:

```
(function($) {
    var reverse = {
        test: function () {
            alert('test');
        },

        fn: function(params) {
            reverse.test();

            /* the rest of your plugin code */
        }
    }

    // jQuery plugin definition
    $.fn.reverseText = reverse.fn
})(jQuery);
```

There is no one "correct" way. Just use whatever works best for the project that you are currently working on.

Comment: Cool thanks alec :) I'll try that way out and see how I like it.